# Where to apply Batch Normalisation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

I have input data and I am passing it through the relu-hidden layer. I wanted to ask where should I apply Batch Normalisation? Following is the model architecture:

```
def function(self, data):
    hidden_layer = F.relu((self.layer1(data)))
    pred = self.pred(hidden_layer)
    pred = self.softmax(pred)
    return pred
```

My best guess is that it should go on the hidden layer like `self.batch_norm(hidden_layer)`. The input data is already scaled using `X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)`

Comment: Yes! it should go on the hidden layer. You are right

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple menmonic ... once your data pass through *any* layer, they're no longer in their original form -- and, most important, they're no longer in a *batch*.

The only place you have available for an effective batch-norm is just before you enter the first hidden layer.

In many (most?) implementations, the observations of a batch are run through the layers in series, one at a time; results are accumulated at the last layer.  "Batch" in this case refers most to the back-prop staging: we defer back-prop until we've run all the observations in the batch, and then update per the batch averages.

For any layer interface, it's possible to counteract vanishing or exploding weights with normalization -- this may be what's confusing you.  However, it's usually best to (1) not get your fingers in there until you know you need to; (2) do it as part of back-propagation -- again bringing in the "batch" synchronization.

Comment: does that mean `hidden_layer = F.relu(self.batch_norm(self.linear1(data_1)))`?

Comment: Do I need to apply it again after I get the output from the hidden layer? If I do what you are saying I can't observe any difference on the graph as shown https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html. The contours are not smooth.

Comment: Ah ... for these, I wouldn't expect an observable difference.  What led you to believe that you'd need batch-norm on these data sets?

Comment: I was trying to do it on the toy dataset. Should I use larger dataset?

Comment: Not necessarily -- batch-norm is needed only when some batches are notably *not* representative of the data set overall, and pull the training off a good, central search path.  For nicely-behaved data sets, you won't notice any difference.  To see a difference in progression, you'd need something like a two-cluster data set, taking the first few batches entirely from one cluster.

Comment: any synthetic data (2-D) that you know of?

Comment: No; where I do these things, I've always generated my own data sets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184538/discussion-between-prune-and-amy).